# product of two vectors equal a positive definite matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra

Given two vectors $v$ and $w$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$, what are conditions on $v$ and $w$ so that $vw^\intercal$ is a positive definite matrix?

Comment: You require that $n=1$, unless you mean a positive *semidefinite* matrix. For semidefiniteness, you require that $v=\lambda w$ with $\lambda\ge0$, because otherwise there always exists a vector $u$ such that $u^Tv$ and $w^Tu$ have different signs.

Comment: Put another way, your matrix has rank $1.$

Comment: $(vw^t) x = vw^tx = v (w^t x) \in \mathbb R v$ so the matrix has rank 1.